# Cannot suspend UbuntuStudio

Tags: 22.04, suspend, power-management, thinkpad, ubuntu-studio

### Environment

- Ubuntu Studio 22.04
- Thinkpad E14 Gen5

### Problem

Cannot suspend UbuntuStudio.
I executed the following steps.

1. Press the power button and try to suspend
2. The screen turns off, but the login screen appears automatically immediately.
3. Execute `sudo dmesg | grep suspend`

```
# sudo dmesg | grep suspend
 [515619.390346] PM: suspend entry (s2idle)
 [515619.500257] printk: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
 [515620.095486] nvme 0000:01:00.0: PM: pci_pm_suspend(): nvme_suspend+0x0/0x1b0 [nvme] returns -16
 [515620.095512] nvme 0000:01:00.0: PM: dpm_run_callback(): pci_pm_suspend+0x0/0x1c0 returns -16
 [515620.095524] nvme 0000:01:00.0: PM: failed to suspend async: error -16
 [515620.279675] PM: Some devices failed to suspend, or early wake event detected
 [515620.992465] PM: suspend exit
 [515620.992571] PM: suspend entry (s2idle)
 [515621.009229] printk: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
 [515621.124693] nvme 0000:01:00.0: PM: pci_pm_suspend(): nvme_suspend+0x0/0x1b0 [nvme] returns -16
 [515621.124735] nvme 0000:01:00.0: PM: dpm_run_callback(): pci_pm_suspend+0x0/0x1c0 returns -16
 [515621.124753] nvme 0000:01:00.0: PM: failed to suspend async: error -16
 [515621.547872] PM: Some devices failed to suspend, or early wake event detected
 [515622.292522] PM: suspend exit
```